# How to match a python formatstring to elements in a list?

Tags: python, design-patterns, format, match

I use Python and there's a list of file names of different file types. Text files may look like these:

```
01.txt
02.txt
03.txt
...
```

Let's assume the text files are all numbered in this manner. Now I want to get all the text files with the number ranging from 1 to 25. So I would like to provide a formatstring like `%02i.txt` via GUI in order to identify all the matching file names.

My solution so far is a nested `for` loop. The outer loop iterates over the whole list and the inner loop counts from 1 to 25 for every file:

```py
fmt = '%02i.txt'
for f in files:
    for i in range(1, 25+1):
        if f == fmt % i:
            # do stuff
```

This nested loop doesn't look very pretty and the complexity is *O(n²)*. So it could take a while on very long lists. **Is there a smarter/pythonic way of doing this?**

Well, yes, I could use a regular expression like `^\d{2}\.txt$`, but a formatstring with `%` is way easier to type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a set:

```
fmt = '%02i.txt'
targets = {fmt % i for i in range(1, 25+1)}
```

then

```
for f in files:
    if f in targets:
        # do stuff
```

Comment: Nice solution. I used this one. :-)

Answer (score 0):

A more pythonic way to iterate through files is through use of the [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module.

```
>>> import glob
>>> for f in glob.iglob('[0-9][0-9].txt'):
        print f


01.txt
02.txt
03.txt
```

Comment: I wouldn't call the `glob` module *pythonic*, while a good use of `set`s usually is.

Comment: @RikPoggi It was a module designed to find file names that follow a pattern. The patterns can only be simple though and in this case it is so I don't see any reason not to use it. I'm under the impression you should make use of the built-in modules if you can.

Comment: Yours is a very good answer, I was just debating on the *"more pythonic"* statement: `glob` might be the canonical way to solve the OP problem, but this doesn't make it neither pythonic or more pythonic.